# What is the reliability of the Service Now web service and how to plan workaround if web services fail

Tags: web-services, servicenow

Though it is not a direct programming related query, I was looking out for the approach one should have if web services fail in Service Now application. How to handle the data at source during the web service outage and how to trigger data transfer after the resolution of web service incident?

Answer (score 0):

Posted the same question in Service Now community and the response is

"Service Now operates 16 data centers and availability is 99.995%. You can try store and process functionality at source during Service Now down time."

The business continuity is planned in such a way that the web-service will failover to another DC causing no disruption to the users/applications.

So the risk is very minimal (infact near to 0) and the scenario can be ignored.